# How to remove same list from matrix by python

Tags: python

How to do that?

```
matrixA = 
[['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'],
['DDD','EEE','FFF'],
['GGG', 'HHH', 'III']]
```

need to remove listA from matrixA

```
listA = ['DDD', 'EEE', 'FFF']
```

Desired output:

```
output_matrix = 
[['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'],
['GGG', 'HHH', 'III']]
```

Please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the help of `remove()` function

```py
matrixA = [['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'],
           ['DDD','EEE','FFF'],
           ['GGG', 'HHH', 'III']]

listA = ['DDD', 'EEE', 'FFF']

matrixA.remove(listA)
```

```
print(matrixA)

>> [['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'], ['GGG', 'HHH', 'III']]
```

Answer (score 1):

For a single remove you can use `list.remove()`

```
matrixA.remove(listA)
```

If you want to use more, we can use a simply list comprehension to generate a list using only elements not in `listA`

```
matrixA = [['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'],
['DDD','EEE','FFF'],
['GGG', 'HHH', 'III']]

listA = [['DDD', 'EEE', 'FFF'], ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']]

output = [group for group in matrixA if group not in listA]
print(output)
#[['GGG', 'HHH', 'III']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `remove` to remove elements. If no element is provided, then exception is raised.

```
matrixA = [['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'],['DDD','EEE','FFF'],['GGG', 'HHH', 'III']]
listA = ['DDD', 'EEE', 'FFF']
matrixA.remove(listA)
print(matrixA)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also iterate on your list (if you want to do more complex comparison):

```
matrixA = [['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'], ['DDD','EEE','FFF'], ['GGG', 'HHH', 'III']]
matrixB = []
listA = ['DDD', 'EEE', 'FFF']

for line in matrixA:
    if line != listA:
        matrixB.append(line)

print(matrixB)
```

Output:

```
[['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'], ['GGG', 'HHH', 'III']]
```

Comment: This is too far unneeded, but thanks for the answer!